# PackageInfo: requestedPermissions vs permissions

Tags: android, permissions

What is the difference between `requestedPermissions` and `permissions`?

```
PackageInfo _pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 
                                               PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

// permissions
PermissionInfo[] _permissions = _pi.permissions;

// requestedPermissions
String[] _requestedPermissions = _pi.requestedPermissions;
```

Is it about application's permissions and OS's permissions?

Thanks

Comment: Requested permissions, I believe, are permissions that are requested, but have not necessarily (yet) been granted. `PermissionInfo` is about the permission itself https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/18573139/1256219 for checking requested permissions and confirmation in the comments

Answer (score 2):

As in the documentation

> public PermissionInfo[]
>
> Array of all `<permission>` tags included under `<manifest>`, or null if
>   there were none.

and

> int[] requestedPermissions
>
> Array of all `<uses-permission>` tags included under `<manifest>`, or null
>   if there were none.

so `permissionInfo` will have the `attributes` in `manifest` tag in manifest for e.g.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.androidtest"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

and

requstedPermissions will return the permissions in `<uses-permission>`tag for e.g

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: I don't think you are correct. `PermissionInfo` contains information regarding the permission itself? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html

Comment: @brandall refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestPermission)

Comment: I think the first part (`permissionInfo`) is not true... but the second part is. I found this from docs: `permissionInfo` Is information you can retrieve about a particular security permission known to the system.  This corresponds to information collected from the AndroidManifest.xml's `<permission>` tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450839/

Comment: @downvoter it is best practice to comment the reason of downvoting

Answer (score -1):

if you want get all permissions pre checked in manifest you must use code below:

```
private bool PermissionInManifest (string permission)
{
    var permissions = this.Activity.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(this.Activity.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.Permissions);
    var requestedPermissions = permissions.RequestedPermissions.ToList();
    return requestedPermissions.Contains(permission);
}
```

if you want check permission granted by user or not, you can use:

```
private bool PermissionGranted (string permission)
{
    return this.Activity.PackageManager.CheckPermission (permission, this.Activity.PackageName) == Permission.Granted;
}
```